# Updating ListView data onItemClick

Tags: android-listview

My code does update the ListView when onItemClick is fired but only if I replace the line "inside the onItemClick method"

```
                categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with the line

```
            lv.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(categories));
```

Should I replace the line as indicated above or the notifyDataSetChanged is what I should use? since the docs say that it should update the view as well.

besides, when I do that, the app runs but hitting the back button shuts the app down instead of go back to the last screen which what I like to see.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView lv;
String[] categories = null;
private static String[] failCategories = {"a","b","c};
private static String[] category_a= { "a1","a2"};

CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCategories);
    categories = failCategories;        //initial set
    categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories);
    lv.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0){
                categories = category_a;
                categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });
}

private class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    CategoryAdapter(String[] objects) {
        super(getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_categories,R.id.tvCategory, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
        return convertView;                 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

please try this part of code inside your code if you want to update respected item only, make sure category_a has equal items

**Version 1**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                categoryAdapter.insert(position,category_a[position]);  
                categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
```

**Version 2**
if you want to update whole listview with all items in category_a then

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    categoryAdapter.clear();
                    categoryAdapter.addAll(category_a);                
                    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Comment: Do you want to update respected value from  category_a to listview or replace whole values of  listview by  category_a on item click?

Comment: replace the whole values, so that the listview shows nothing but the new data from category_a. thx

Comment: please use version 2 in my answer

Comment: version 2 of your answer gives .ClassCastException: .assignment1.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener

Comment: as I indicated that this line works (lv.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(categories));) why not use it? thx

Comment: That is fine, It recreates object every time so I think it is not good idea even if it works. can you change categoryAdapter in my code to lv.getAdapter()

Comment: then the IDE can not resolve the methods clear, addAll and notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: ((ArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter()) resolves but IDE gives unsupportedExecption and app crashes.

Comment: I abandoned this approach since the phone back button will destroy the activity thus the child list instead of going to the parent list. Thank  you